# In special relativity, how do we know that distance doesn't change in the direction perpendicular to velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, thought-experiment

In the theory of special relativity it is said that the distance in the direction of the speed changes by a factor of
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$$

How do we know that the distance perpendicular to the velocity doesn't change?

Comment: You give the answer in your title: Special Relativity.

Comment: But why does speciel relativity tell us there is no change in the perpandicular direction

Comment: How much do you know about special relativity? Its a pretty basic fact so pointing us to your knowledge will help us explain it.

Comment: @seanpython To understand , why distance does not change in the direction perpendicular to velocity, you first need to understand why it DOES change in the direction along the velocity. You need to know how that formula is derived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider two thin cylinders, each of radius $r$ in their own rest frame, moving towards each other with their axes aligned.

Suppose that distances in the perpendicular direction shrink. Then each cylinder observes the other as shrunken and has a radius less than $r.$ Each cylinder finds that the other cylinder will pass directly through it.

Two cylinders cannot both pass inside each other, but the situation is symmetric. There is no way to choose which cylinder should shrink, and so if the universe obeys the symmetries of special relativity, neither cylinder can shrink.

The same argument applies to the cylinders expanding, so they can neither shrink nor expand, showing that distances in the perpendicular direction are the same between frames.

This argument appears in *Spacetime Physics* by Taylor and Wheeler, but I don't know if it's original to that book.

Comment: Thats a great argument, thanks

Comment: The concentric cylinders approach is in Spacetime Physics (2ed (1991), Ch 3.6 Invariance of Transverse Dimension, p.66). I couldn't find a similar argument in the first edition (only a statement was provided in 1ed (1966), B.9, p.64 "Lorentz contraction-a worked example").   Feynman uses a "marks on each other’s y-meter stick" approach in Feynman Lectures vol I, ch 15 The Special Theory of Relativity (15-4 Transformation of time) end of the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is straightforward. The formula shows that there is no dilation when your speed is zero, which is what you would expect, otherwise length dilation would be observable in connection with stationary objects. The component of your speed perpendicular to your direction of motion is always zero, hence dilation must be zero in that direction.

Comment: This is incorrect logic so I gave a down-vote. The logic is incorrect because the quoted formula is not, on its own, enough to go from a 1-dimensional to a 3-dimensional treatment.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Why do you consider the logic incorrect?

Comment: I said why: a formula that has been arrived at in a 1-dimensional treatment does not itself carry over to 3D so cannot be assumed to apply to the three components of a vector individually. That would have to be derived by setting up a 3D calculation in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, Andrew, then can you explain why you think the formula was arrived at in a 1-d treatment? I can derive the formula for length contraction in 3D with the result that there is no contraction when there is no motion. It follows that where an object is moving in an arbitrary direction, in 3D the contraction is zero in the directions in which the components of velocity are zero.

Comment: The original question is from one who knows of Lorentz contraction and asks why there is no transverse effect. If you wish to present a derivation in 3D then that would answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can simply derive this from the Lorentz transform. With the $x$ direction parallel and the $y$, $z$ directions perpendicular the Lorentz transform is: $$t'=\gamma \left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2} \right)$$ $$x'=\gamma (x - vt)$$ $$ y' = y$$ $$z' = z$$ For an object with a length $L$ in the $y$ direction at rest in the unprimed frame we have the worldlines of the ends as $y_0 = y$ and $y_L= y+L$ so the distance between the ends is $y_L-y_0=L$.

To obtain the distance in the primed frame we simply transform $y'_0=y=y'$ and $y'_L=y+L=y'+L$ so the distance is $y'_L-y'_0=L$.

Therefore the distance in the perpendicular direction does not contract.

Comment: This is true but by quoting the Lorentz transformation at the start it invites the question, but why does the Lorentz transformation take that form?

Comment: It takes that form because it has to account for us seeing the same speed of light when we are moving relative to each other, and crucially when we are not. The transformation has to have no effect when two observers are not moving relative to each other. Therefore is must have no effect in any direction perpendicular to the direction of motion, ie any direction in which the relative velocity is zero.

Comment: @MarcoOcram hello again; I think the "therefore" at the start of your last sentence here requires further justification. For example, there is no Doppler effect for no relative motion, but there is a transverse Doppler effect. Thus the mere fact that something vanishes for zero velocity does not in itself tell us what effect to expect in directions perpendicular to a non-zero velocity. Obviously we know the answer in this case, but the issue is how that answer is derived or argued-for.

Comment: I think you are going in circles, Andrew! The mere fact that something vanishes for zero velocity tells us that it vanishes for zero velocity. There is no direction perpendicular to zero velocity. Perhaps I am missing something, so let's keep up the chat! Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to understand this is to figure out why we needed special relativity in the first place.

One of the fundamental principles of Physics is that no matter which frame of reference you go to, the laws of Physics should remain same (Also known as lorentz invariance). Relativity was introduced by Galileo and Newton creating what is traditionally known as classical mechanics. The problem that arose was that when classical electromagnetic theory was applied to Maxwell's equations (more specifically to moving charges) things went haywire. There were asymmetries that started to rise up. Classical relativity and electromagnetism were not working together and thus something was wrong.

So we needed some new formulation of relativity which can have a transformation (not galilean) that makes all physical laws looking the same + the speed of light is same in all frames. While the second condition may look arbitrary, it comes out from the electrodynamics issue.

Lets start the derivation. We have two inertial frames F and F' in which a light front is moving and they have a relative velocity of v (in the x direction). The equation for this would be
$ x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2t^2 $ and in the second frame it would be $x'^2+y'^2+z'^2=c^2t'^2$. Once you solve these equations and try to find relationships between x,x' y,y' z,z' t,t' you end up with the so called lorentz transformation. These transformation laws show us that length contraction happens in whichever direction the relative velocity is between the two frames. ( $x'=\gamma (x-vt) \mathrm{\: and\: }y'=y\: z'=z$)